# Avoiding methods returning Wildcard types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Here's my application design where I'm trying to avoid returning wildcard types from my method so that I can invoke the methods on the returned object.  Any suggestions?  Is it a poor idea to have a static utility method to find and return the right handler implementation like below after all?

**The problem:**
I have a bunch of requests (and responses corresponding to them). These requests have to be handled and the results of the handling (the responses) may be used for further processing. Which request to be handled at a given moment depends on a few criteria (this is an `enum`).

**My approach:**
My solution was to build several handlers, one for each of the request-response type combos and having them all implement a common interface with a method to handle the request.

Here's how it goes:

A family of handler classes implementing the `Handler` interface:

```
interface Handler<Q extends Request, R extends Response> {
  R handleRequest(Q);
}
```

and a static utility method companion class to find the right handler matching the given criteria:

```
class Handlers {
  Handler<? extends Request, ? extends Response> handlerForCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
    switch (criteria):
    ...
    // since there are several handler implementations, I couldn't avoid the wildcard 
    // types for the request and response
  }
}
```

Here's where I need to use it:

```
Handler<? extends Request, ? extends Response> matchingHandler = 
    Handlers.handlerForCriteria(criteria);
MyResponse response = matchingHandler.handleRequest(myRequest);
```

I'd like to be able to call the `handleRequest` like above, but obviously I'm not allowed to since the `matchingHandler` contains wildcard types (it can't tell for certain if the unknown wildcard type of the request was the same type as `myRequest).

Comment: Probably the @Bohemian answer would satisfy you, but if not, could you please add more context? Post a sample implementation of any handler and sample usage. How you'd like to use the returned `Handler` from `handlerForCriteria`? And what is `Criteria` object? Probably your *original* problem can be solved in another way.

Comment: @TagirValeev,  added a bit more context and the original problem I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to see if answer would satisfy my need, but it looks like it isn't the cleanest of approaches. I will add a comment on why I think it isn't really what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a typed method with a cast if necessary:

```
class Handlers {
    <R extends Request, T extends Response> Handler<R, T> handlerForCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        Handler<?, ?> handler = someStrategryThatIsUntyped();
        return (Handler<R, T>)handler; // just cast
    }
}
```

---

So, why/when is the cast "safe"?

Sometimes the case is both needed and safe. For example, consider this code:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Handler<?>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
```

And you populate it in a way that guarantees that the type of the class equals the type of the handler (which can't be done in the map's declaration):

```
public <T> void register(Class<T> clazz, Handler<T> handler) {
    handlers.put(clazz, handler);
}
```

but the method that finds the handler can't be compiled safely based on the map's definition:

```
public <T> Handler<T> findHandler(Class<T> clazz) {
    Handler<?> handler = handlers.get(clazz);
    // Although the compiler can't assert it, the handler is of type T
    // The cast is safe, because we programmatically constrain map's entries
    return (Handler<T>)handler; // safe
}
```

Comment: Quite dangerous advice. This cast is not controlled in any way. You may have unexpected ClassCastException much later when you use the returned handler...

Comment: @TagirValeev sometimes it's both totally safe and totally needed. See update for example situation. Oh, and BTW I really like the posts you've been making - excellent stuff :)

Comment: I agree, sometimes, such a cast is completely safe and needed. So I proceeded to implement it this way. It definitely isn't the cleanest (having to suppress an `unchecked` warning during the cast), but it is what it is I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

Firstly, for most cases the below solution works if it is not required to know the precise type of only `Response`.

```
class Handlers {
    static Handler<? super Request,? extends Response> handlerForCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        return null;
    }
}
class CustomRequest implements Request{}

Handler<? super Request, ? extends Response> handler = Handlers.handlerForCriteria(null);
Response response = handler.handleRequest(new CustomRequest() {});
```

---

I find it philosophically wrong to precisely know the return type in this case. if you expect that the return type is say `CustomResponse`, it is your reliance on that fact that `handleForCriteria` for that argument will always return `CustomResponse`. What if it changes in future. Extra maintenance effort.

```
static <E extends Request, T extends Response> Handler<E,T> handlerForCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        return null;
    }
 Handler<CustomRequest, CustomResponse> handler = Handlers.handlerForCriteria(null);
 CustomResponse response = handler.<CustomResponse>handleRequest(new CustomRequest() {});
```

In case if you know it strongly then probably above might be a solution. But I would never do it. I would rather prefer manual type-casting than having a generic type parameter at method level.

Comment: The actual response type is not really what I'd definitely need to know. What I'd be interested in is to be able to invoke the `handleRequest` using the handler returned by the `Handlers` utility. Looks like there's no clean way to do it. Also did you really mean: `? super Request`? That isn't what I'm expecting it to be - I'd expected the request type to be a _subtype_ of `Request`.

Comment: @mystarrocks `? super Request` does not mean it will be be a super type. It basically means that your type `T` will `T < (? super Request)`. Hence it goes better with writes. This is similar to definition of `Function.andThen`